# Is it possible to edit the raw text of a task field directly in AzDo web?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to edit the text of the description field of an AzDo task directly as  used to be an option in TFS. Despite the rich text editing options, I sometimes find that the editor doesn't provide all the functionality I want, or that there is lingering malformed text after clearing formatting. Does the web version of AzDo provide this functionality? If so, how can I edit the raw text?

Comment: Why the close vote? Feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. it is possible only for **On-premises XML** (local TFS or Azure DevOps Server). For the cloud solution, we can not change the field type: [Manage work item fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/manage-work-item-fields?view=azure-devops)

> For the On-premises XML process model, you can use witadmin to list,
> import, export, and modify a process for a project. For the Inherited
> and Hosted XML process models, you can only use witadmin to list and
> export process information.
>
> When you upgrade Team Foundation Server from an earlier version to the
> current version, the type assignment for the Description
> (System.Description) field is automatically converted from PlainText
> to HTML. With the changefield command, you can restore the content of
> this field to display plain text.